# "opposite" used as a noncount noun?

Tags: grammar, colloquialisms

We can find sentences like the one below from the Merriam-Webster dictionary:

*"Wet" **is the opposite of** "dry."*

But I've heard others say "Wet **is opposite of** dry."

Is the latter correct? Why can't I find any dictionary that says the word opposite can be used as a noncount noun? Or if it is an adjective, why can't I still find this kind of phrase "be opposite of?"

Comment: In principle you *could* omit the article and say *"Wet" is opposite **to** "dry",* but note that you'd have to change the preposition. The sequence [*evil is opposite **to** good*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22evil+is+opposite+to+good%22), for example, gets 182 hits in Google Books, but there are no instances at all of [*evil is opposite **of** good*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22evil+is+opposite+of+good%22).

Comment: @FumbleFingers. But be opposite to means " on the other side of something." There is a subtle difference between them. Be the opposite of means "completely different from something" according to the dictionary.

Comment: Please look at this activity book: [Making connections](https://books.google.com.tw/books?id=G7PhBAAAQBAJ&pg=PP4&dq=%22is+opposite+of%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi1t-aJoI_MAhWLGpQKHbEFDHs4ChDoAQgjMAI#v=onepage&q=%22is%20opposite%20of%22&f=false)

Comment: Your *"the opposite of" means "completely different from something"* is a somewhat loose definition. If I say [*cats are the opposite of dogs*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22cats+are+the+opposite+of+dogs%22), for example, I'm completely ignoring the fact that cats and dogs are in most respects very similar (both are quadruped mammals often kept as pets, etc., so they're nowhere near as different as, say, cats and toasters). Things that are opposite are (figuratively) on orthogonally opposite sides of **some contextually-relevant distinction***.

Comment: Both are correct, in the right contexts.

Comment: See the online Oxford dictionary: *2 Completely different; of a contrary kind.
‘a word that is opposite in meaning to another’
‘currents flowing in opposite directions’*

Answer (score 3):

This sounds like the others are using the [prepositional form of *opposite*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/opposite#Preposition).

> ### Preposition
>
> **opposite**
>
> 1. Facing, or across from.
>
>    > *He lives **opposite** the pub.‎*
> 2. In a complementary role to.
>
>    > *He played **opposite** Marilyn Monroe.‎*

<sup>From [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/opposite#Preposition)</sup>

> ### PREPOSITION
>
> 1. In a position on the other side of a specific area from; facing.
>
>    > *‘they sat opposite one another’*
> 2. (of a leading actor) in a complementary role to (another)
>
>    > *‘the star was a young man playing opposite an older woman’*

<sup>From [English Oxford *Living* Dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/opposite)</sup>

This would be **incorrect**, but understandable. Apparently, *opposite* can be used as an adjective, noun, adverb, and/or preposition depending on the context, and a casual English speaker might not know which context demands which form.

Comment: @Clare I've added an example from OED. Not sure what you were seeing when you looked. Perhaps re-read my answer more carefully? I specifically talk about the _prepositional_ form, whereas you seem to be quoting the second _adjective_ form.

Comment: That's the same dictionary I'm quoting. And it's the Oxford dictionary online  called ODO, around here. The OED (*Oxford English Dictionary*)  is not a  free dictionary.

Comment: Yes, I was quoting the adjectival form. I have removed my downvote. On the other hand  I usually encourage folks to use professionally-compiled dictionaries, such as Oxford.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. I've corrected the citation beneath the ODO example.